# if looping a dictionary through int values

Tags: python

```
courses = {"mon":20,
       "tues":25,
       "wed":13,
       "thurs":5,
       "fri":25}
for value in courses:
    if value == 25:
        print("course is full")
    elif value >= 20 and key<=24:
        print("course is almost full")
    elif value<20:
        print("plenty of seats left") #here
```

I get the type error '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
How can I fix my code?

Comment: `for value in courses.values():`

Comment: You want to iterate over the values of a dict, so you need `for value in courses.values()`. Also, fix your indentation

Answer (score 1):

Note when you iterate through a dictionary you iterate through the keys of the dictionary. Not the values.

```
courses = {
   "mon":20,
   "tues":25,
   "wed":13,
   "thurs":5,
   "fri":25
}
for day, value in courses.items():
    if value == 25:
        print(f"{day} course is full")
    elif value >= 20 and value<=24:
        print(f"{day} course is almost full")
    elif value<20:
        print(f"{day} course has plenty of seats left")
```

This is most likely what you want to have.

To get just the values iterate through `courses.values()` instead of `courses.items()`

Answer (score 0):

Looping through a dictionary gives you the keys, not the values. You could do the following.

```
courses = {"mon":20,
       "tues":25,
       "wed":13,
       "thurs":5,
       "fri":25}
for key in courses:
    if courses[key] == 25:
        print("course is full")
    elif courses[key] >= 20 and courses[key] <= 24:
        print("course is almost full")
    elif courses[key]<20:
        print("plenty of seats left") here
```

Alternatively, you could loop through the values directly with `for value in courses.values():`.

Comment: `courses[key] <= 24` not `key <= 24` most likely ;)

Answer (score 0):

value are str (key) and can't be used with comparison operator and int
No need to evaluate two condition in between, `elif` surely trigger once only when it satisfied the condition..

```
for value in courses.values():
    if value >= 25: print("course is full")
    elif value >= 20: print("course is almost full")
    elif value < 20: print("plenty of seats left")
```